# Why cant I use .sum in a Stateful Widget?

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I have built out a stateless widget that I now need to change to a stateful widget. Within my stateless widget, I have a function...

```
            SumOfRoundedTankValue() {
              List<double> numbers = [];
                port.ports.tankSpecs.forEach((e) {
                  numbers.add(double.parse(e.defUsGallons));
              });
                final sum = numbers.sum;
                return (sum);
            }
```

Why does this function not work in a stateful widget? I get the squiggly line under .sum that says:

> The getter 'sum' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'sum', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'sum'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not issue of `Statless` or `Statefull` widgets

Just import to your `dart` file

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

After that `sum` property will be available to your `Iterable`

```
final sum = numbers.sum;
```

Comment: I cant believe I missed that... When I changed my widget to a stateful one, I thought I moved all of my imports over.. I apparently missed that one..  >.<. Thank you!!